# Do jumping puzzle rewards scale to your level?

Tags: guild-wars-2

I was already level 34 when I found out about jumping puzzles.  How do the rewards for these puzzles work?  Is it worth it to go back to the starter area and complete those puzzles?  If they *do* scale, wouldn't it be wise to save them until I'm level 80?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The grand, magnificent or splendid chests found at the end of some jumping puzzles do scale to your level, however they also reset after a certain amount of time. Due to this there really isn't any reason to wait to perform the jumping puzzle. If you're really hurting for items at level 80 you can just go back and do the jumping puzzle again. Realistically though, you'd be better off buying items off the trading post or crafting them to easily get your first tier of level 80 items.

Comment: I can't seem to find an official source right now, but jumping puzzle chests reset every 24-hours (from the time you open them).

Comment: Pretty sure they reset with the dailies (though you may need to reload the zone if you just opened one)